# Algorithms in preprocessed universe

Tags: ds.algorithms, ds.data-structures, online-algorithms, fine-grained

In celebrated paper *Clustered integer 3SUM via additive combinatorics* by TM Chan and M Lewenstein one of the provided algorithms is the one for preprocessed universe.   They were able to provide an algorithm with running time $O(n^{13/7})$ for solving 3-Sum on the subset of the universe of size $n$, assuming some preprocessing was allowed.

What other examples of such algorithms in preprocessed universe do you know?

Comment: binary search ​ ​

Answer (score 2):

- As Ricky Demer said in his comment, many search problems can be sped up with sorting or building some other index structure
- Lowest common ancestor queries can be answered in constant time with linear preprocessing.
- Lots of text problems can be sped up with some preprocessing, e.g. building a suffix array